# How to show only controller name in the case of Index action in MVC 5 Url?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This may be a dumb question but i am new to asp.net MVC . Thanks in advance .

How can i show the controller name only in the case of the Index action ?

E.g. `http://localhost/Account/Index to http://localhost/Account/`.

How can i do this ? Thanks .

Comment: can you show your routes?

Comment: If you are using the default route, then `http://localhost/Account` will navigate to the `Index()` method.

Comment: I am using default route. I  don't want Index in my url only the controller name in the case of Index action .

Comment: But `Index` will not be shown if you using the default route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your e.g 
**http://localhost/Account/Index** here the Index action of the Account Conttroller will be invoked and in **http://localhost/Account/** again the Index action will be invoked because you might have mentioned the default action as Index while defining the route in RouteConfig.cs file and also you have not mentioned the action name in the url so as your default action in route is Index, the index action of the controller will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

This line is showing what URL user passed to browser. So if he pass `http://localhost/Account/Index` you can only use [`Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx) method in your controller to change URL. But be carefull, you can lose Context in that case.

But if you asking about why when you pass only `http://localhost/Account/`   Action method `Index` called then you should take a look at `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder. There is a default routing defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = new NullableConstraint() }
);
```